# Multiple topics on a single partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I was just curious and could not find any info on this. My question is can there be multiple topics on a single partition? If yes, how will they be produced in that partition or consumed by a consumer later? Or is it that one partition always holds one topic?

Comment: A single partition ALWAYS corresponds to a single topic. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kafka, one partition always holds data related to one topic. Having multiple topics data in one partition is little unusual use-case. If I understood your use-case correctly, If you want to store multiple datasets in one topic and one partition (which is not recommended though) then you can create flag field in input data which reveals that document belongs to particular dataset.

Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 4):

Kafka partition belongs only to one topic. Topic is higher level construct which is broken into partition, so there is guarantee that single partition never belongs to more than one topic.